# Nav bar links don't resize with background-color

Tags: html, css, background-color, nav

*I'm basically new to HTML/CSS so I'm not sure how to describe my problem. I apologize if things are unclear.*

[image: Nav bar and background-color out of sync]

I have a web site with a navigation bar across the top of the page. I want the margins between the links to shrink with the resizing of the window. However, only the background color seems to change when I adjust it's size in Firefox. This leaves me with a menu bar that stretches out of view when the screen is shrunken horizontally.

I've tried removing the margin and word-spacing properties as well as adding the "display: flex" property, but nothing seems to help. (Usually my edits makes things worse.)

PS: This problem started after trying to add the 'ul' tag to the 'nav' links.

```css
nav {
  background-color: #3BD9D9;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 30px;
  /*word-spacing: 1em;*/
  position: f;
  display: flex;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: #0A46BF;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="../services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="../shopping/shop.html">Shop</a></li>
    <!--    <ul>
            <li><a href="#monitors">Monitors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#cases">Cases</a></li>
        </ul><!-->
    <li><a href="../reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="../contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="../about.html">About/FAQ</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between`

```css
nav {
  background-color: #3BD9D9;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 30px;
  /*word-spacing: 1em;*/
  position: f;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: #0A46BF;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="../services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="../shopping/shop.html">Shop</a></li>
    <!--    <ul>
            <li><a href="#monitors">Monitors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#cases">Cases</a></li>
        </ul><!-->
    <li><a href="../reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="../contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="../about.html">About/FAQ</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Was 'justify-content' really all I needed? Well, it seems to be working much more like how I wanted it to. Thanks for saving me from another day of headache.

Comment: you should set display css to `flex` to use justify-content

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content

Answer (score 0):

It happens because resizing the screen the ul tags became bigger than its container.

To avoid it you can add an overflow property to your nav (es. overflow: scroll) (bad choise).

Anyway the best way to sove this problem is making your design responsive using for example bootstrap responsive navbar:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/

or media queries:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp